# Prevent Visual Studio 2010 from starting ASP.net development server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vs-unit-testing-framework, aspnet-development-server

I have 3 projects in my solution.

Whenever I attempt to debug a unit test in any of the projects, VS2010 starts 3 (1 for each project) ASP.net development servers.

The issue I have is that VS2010 takes a long time starting these development servers and as a result I spend a lot of time waiting whilst I attempt to debug unit tests.

I am not sure why VS2010 does this... Is there a valid reason? Is there a way to prevent these development servers from starting when debugging unit tests?

Answer (score 20):

Not sure why it does this by default, but if your question is really "how do I turn this off", then do this:

1. Select the ASP.NET project in your
   solution
2. Press F4 to bring up the
   properties (not the properties tab
   you get when choosing Properties
   from the context menu)
3. Change Development Server -> Always Start
   When Debugging to "False"

Comment: It would be nice if it stored this preference in the .suo file, or the solution file based on the build configuration.

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't included in the Project properties, ty!